# How to get only column value of a dataframe (without reference formula)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to get only column value of csv file rather then reference formula.

```
 df_csv = pd.read_csv(file_name)
 print(df_csv["column_head"])
```

the output is not the value. It is a csv reference formula.

```
0    =ROUND(IF(J2,I2/J2,0),4)
1    =ROUND(IF(J3,I3/J3,0),4)
```

But I want only cell values not the formula. How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems to be wrong with the format of the file you read from.
I checked on a spreadsheet containing formulas for some cells. here as an example:

[image: XLTest]

The 'D' column contains moving averages from the 'B' column.
I saved the spreadsheet as a 'xlsx' file and as a 'csv' file.

For the first, importing with:

```
import pandas as pd
df_ex = pd.read_excel("xltest.xlsx")
df_ex = df_ex[df_ex['Global 10 years MA'].notnull()]
df_ex.head()
```

and the second, importing with:

```
df_ex2 = pd.read_csv('xltest.csv')
df_ex2[df_ex2['Global 10 years MA'].notnull()].head()
```

both gave this output (note: the 'notnull()' mask is just extracting the lines with a value in this example):

[image]

Extracting the "Column with a Formula" from the first dataframe:

```
ser = df_ex['Global 10 years MA']
ser.head()
```

gives this output:

[image]

As you see, values, and no excel formulas. Check you save your file as xlsx or csv format, in your spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reading from a line which defines the formulas. I would open the csv in excel and then check if I am reading the data right.
use

```
df=pd.read_csv('file_path', header=n); where n is the row number from which data 
                                       starts
```

Comment: I am reading the column  and column has header and the values. But the values are coming from other column using reference formula. I don't want these formula, I just want the values